# What is the "jdbc:mysql:" portion of a database url referred to as?

Tags: java, mysql

I know that it's used at the beginning of a URL string to create a connection to MySQL (or similar DB system), but, what is this portion of the connection string referred to as and what exactly is its function/role?

MySQL example:

```
String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/?useSSL=false";
```

H2 example:

```
String DB_URL = "jdbc:h2:~/DB_NAME";
```

Comment: to identicate the database you want to target

Comment: @Lino Is there a term that's traditionally given to it? Like, "identifier"?

Comment: I don't really know and counter question: is this just out of curiosity or are you really needing that name?

Comment: @Lino Really needing the name. I'm creating a default interface method that has each portion of the url string separate and then using StringBuilder to assemble a url string based on whether db name is present or not, etc. So, I'm wondering what variable name I should give to this substring for it to be most accurate to its functionality / how it's traditionally referred to as.

Comment: Refer : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/connecting.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The generic format of the connection URL is:

> **protocol//[hosts][/database][?properties]**

for your question:

> String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/?useSSL=false";

1. **jdbc:mysql:** is protocol part.
2. hosts part is written in the format of host:port which is- **localhost:3306**
3. **useSSL=false** is properties in key-value pair to disable SSL.

The connection string should be:

> String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/{dbName}?useSSL=false";

You can use this reference for more explanation-
[Connection URL Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-reference-jdbc-url-format.html):

Comment: Is this standard for database connection? If so, who is defining and joining to this standard? I just want to know simple history of it.

Answer (score 2):

From [The components of a URL](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGMCP_5.2.0/com.ibm.cics.ts.internet.doc/topics/dfhtl_uricomp.html)

> A scheme. The scheme identifies the protocol to be used to access the resource on the Internet. It can be HTTP (without SSL) or HTTPS (with SSL).

In this case, it is `jdbc` followed by a more specific driver implementation (which is usually registered via the [`DriverManager`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html)).

Comment: Here is the [WikiPedia equivalent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL) It even has a syntax diagram (a.k.a. pretty picture)

Answer (score 0):

The `jdbc:{database name}` is protocol part. database name can be `mysql, derby, oracle`. The next part of the connection string depends on the individual `DriverManager` implementation. See below connection string :

```
MySQL  : jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql 
Oracle : jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","system","oracle"
Derby  : jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/myDB;create=true;user=me;password=mine
```

Answer (score 0):

It is referred as JDBC connection string (URL) or Database URL.

To access a database from a Java application, you must first provide the code to register your installed driver with your program. Once you have registered the driver, you can open a connection to the database with the static getConnection() method of the java.sql.DriverManager class. The type of the object returned is java.sql.Connection.

**Specifying a Database URL and Properties Object to get connection**
The following signature takes a URL, together with a properties object that specifies user name and password (perhaps among other things):

getConnection(String URL, Properties info);

Where the URL is of the form:

```
`jdbc:oracle:<drivertype>:@<database>`
```

[Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/OracleDriver.html)